# Symfony 4 Adding/Updating Entities from Command

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a command that i run from CLI to import data and create entries.

```js
$doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
/** @var PropertyRepository $propRepo */
$propRepo = $doctrine->getRepository(Property::class);
$propRepo->findOneBy(['id' => $property['PropertyId']])
```

My Command extends ContentAwareCommand ( even tho it says its deprecated it really dont like it )

SO how can i query my repositories from inside this Command?

Comment: You need Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use dependency injection inside your command, you need to pass EntityManagerInterface to your constructor,

```
class SomeCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    private $em;
    function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = em;
        parent::__construct(); // you need to call the parent else command won't show up
    }
    // after this you are free to use entity manager in your command
}
```